# How can we add bootstrap icons (i.e Half-Circle Icon) in flutter just like fontAwesome Icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am dealing with an issue where I need half filled circle icon but I searched a lot and find out that i think flutter Icons or fontAwesomeIcons don't provide us that icon. So I came a cross a bootstrap icons which is providing that icon. Now I want to know how can we insert Bootstrap icons in flutter as we insert fa-fa Icons as fontAwesomeIcons in flutter
Below is the icon's detail

**[Link](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/circle-half/)**

```
<i class="bi bi-circle-half"></i>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-circle-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1v14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 1 8 0a8 8 0 0 1 0 16z"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Required Icon]

Comment: ImageIcon widget may help you, you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks man. I have been working on this for an hour. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Svg file as an icon [flutter_svg package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) (it's less flexible and need add Svg file as asset in your project) or you can create your custom font icons. You just need your icons' Svgs. you can follow this.

1. Go to [fluttericon.com](https://www.fluttericon.com/)
2. Drag your Svgs to custom icons box.
3. Type your favorite name for your font icon (e.g MyIcons).
4. Click on download button. It gives you a font (.ttf) and a flutter class.
5. Add font(.ttf file) to your `pubspec.yaml` file. [read more](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts). Please make sure your your font family is the same as the name your typed above, for example

```
fonts:
    - family: MyIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MyIcons.ttf
```

6. Add a generated class to your project.
7. Use your custom icon. for example

```
Container(
  child: Icon(MyIcon.circle-half),
),
```

Comment: I had tried this method from https://medium.com/codechai/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977 but it didn't help me as it shows not found [X] sign instead of icon

Comment: Did you reset running app? if yes, i think your pubspec is wrong. did you add font family in your pubspec? I edit above code

Comment: Checked everything but didn't helped. but your first solution svgpicture resolved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to add any extra fonts to show half circle
there are `CupertinoIcons.circle_lefthalf_fill` and `CupertinoIcons.circle_righthalf_fill` icons